# mysql only returning results with numeric values

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a random alphanumeric for a public access category that can only be found by using this alphanumeric post id in the url link. Weird thing is that I am only getting results from the query when numeric values are used.

```
 $sql = "SELECT *
 FROM $a
 WHERE access_key = $category_id
```

I get an "unknown column" error containing the alphnumeric data as the column, which I find a little strange. I think this maybe something simple like escaping that needs to be done, but I am not really sure.

Any suggestions would be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: You just need quotes around '$category_id'. But read the comment about sqli.

Comment: fair enough about injection, thanks for the reminder as this is a url request, but this is beta dev where I am avoiding the problems of the prepared statements until I have working code.

Comment: In addition to prepared for the $category_id value, be sure to whitelist whatever $a is gonna have too. Since you cannot prepare a table name (or field name).

Comment: @Randall this is going via wordpress prefix setup, hence $a is built already. Do I need to do more on this?

Comment: Oh. Wordpress... shoulda added that to the tags list ;)

Comment: oops, I will do in future

Comment: Even if it's just a dev prototype, use parameter binding unless you're 100% sure that your code will never be used in production. It's not much work, and you should make it a strict habit.

Comment: Prepared statements are in my general practise, although not alway in select, however maybe I will ensure it more after the warnings. When things are not quite working though, stripping back a little can be helpful.

Comment: sad times for the downvote :-(((((((((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper way to do it, and also fix the error you are seeing.

MYSQLI:

```
// assuming $a is already safe
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM '. $a .' WHERE access_key = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $category_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

PDO:

```
// assuming $a is already safe
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM '. $a .' WHERE access_key = :category_id');
$stmt->execute(array(':category_id'=>$category_id));
```

As for whitelisting... this is a basic example (do it BEFORE any sql actions):

```
$safe = array('categorytable','usertable');
if (!in_array($a,$safe)) { return; exit; die(); /*lol*/ }
```

ORRRRR.... if you just want toquickly fix your current sql line of code (but please do look into doing prepared in the future):

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM $a
        WHERE access_key = '$category_id'";
```

Comment: Thanks, for interest, how does the whitelist add protection?

Comment: eg: how does it prevent attacks

Comment: marking this as correct answer as it does give the simplest correction to the original code, along with addtional info. Although it can be done a little simpler with just     '$category_id'   rather than the      ' " . $cateogry_id . " '

Comment: I adjusted the answer for you :)

Comment: You forgot to throw an exception after return, exit and die ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by tadman, never use direct $_GET or $_POST values in your SQL. Protect it with something like this:

```
Function protectSQL($val, $type=‘text’) {
$val = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($val) : $val;
switch ($type) {
    case "text":
         $val = ($val != "") ? "'" . $val . "'" : "NULL";
         break;
    case "long":
    case "int":
         $val = ($val != "") ? intval($val) : "NULL";
         break;
      }
return $val;
}
```

Since you're not wrapping within apostrophes your value, MySQL thinks its a column. So, write something like this:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE access_key = %s", $a, protectSQL($val)); // $val is passed in the functions above, and $a has to be guaranteed...
```

And you'll get something clean like:

```
echo $sql; // SELECT * FROM table WHERE access_key = 'abc123'
```

Remember that $a is assumed to come from your code, so there is no protection added. If it comes from the client side, a simple in_array command could ensure that it is a valid table.

Comment: Blimey, this is quite something I hadn't considered for protection / seen before. Thanks for the clarification on the column / variable issue. How does the query interpret variables without quotation marks? eg: how dos it see it differently to a variable with qutation marks?

Comment: This does **not** protect you from any type of SQLi! https://3v4l.org/12tlB

Comment: Interesting tool. I couldn't see a result for the "protection" / "safety" of the query though.